# What is th difference between F/UTP , F/FTP and FTP?

Tags: cable, wiring

I am in the following situation :the IT department asked for a wire of type FTP. The company that is cabling the building is using F/UTP. Is it FTP? Or they need another type of cable kind of F/FTP??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair#/media/File:10G_BASE-T_x_3_cables.svg

Comment: Normally they should ask for something like Cat5 or Cat6e or Cat7 or ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I normally would associate FTP with the File Transfer Protocol :)

But from: [belden.com/blog](http://www.belden.com/blog/datacenters/STP-UTP-FTP-Cable-More-7-Types-When-to-Use-Them.cfm)

> **F/UTP (FTP)**
>   An overall foil shield (**F**) with unscreened twisted pairs (**UTP**). This cable is very much like common UTP cables, with the addition of foil underneath the main cable jacket. Another common name for this cable is **FTP. F/UTP** cables are common in 10GBaseT applications.

But to keep the confusion, there are also several variaties of **F**oil screened **T**wisted **P**airs where (also) the individual pairs are shielded:

> **U/FTP**
>   No overall shielding or braid (U) with foil screened twisted pairs (FTP). This type of shielded cable is commonly used in 10GBaseT applications as well.
>
> **S/FTP**
>   An overall braid screen (S) with foil screened twisted pairs (FTP). The “shield” underneath the jacket is a braid, and each individual pair is surrounded by its own foil barrier. The purpose of the additional foil on individual pairs is to limit the amount of crosstalk between them.
>
> **F/FTP**
>   An overall foil shield (F) with foil screened twisted pairs (FTP).

So to answer your question, yes, F/UTP is a type FTP and there are others, all suitable for 10GBaseT.

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/10G_BASE-T_x_3_cables.svg]

Comment: Is SF/FTP better than F/FTP?

Comment: Very informative answer but, what I was personally searching for, was a comparison of the impact this extra shielding has. Say that the cables are installed to run in parallel to power cables (which might be a really bad situation). I guess S/FTP would be better in this case since there is a low-frequency noise ( https://www.belden.com/blogs/smart-building/stp-utp-ftp-cable- ). But I cannot find any charts showing the actual impact given the frequency and noise level for each cable type. So, I cannot say if it is negligible or not. Nor if I need any shielding at all to do my intended job.